# How to implement Zend Translation in Core PHP Project

Tags: php, zend-framework, translation, zend-translate

I need to implement Zend Translation in a project that is made in Core PHP that is i don't want to use Full ZF Just Zend Translation Classes that is used for Translation.

How would i do that means how would i start ?

```
which classes i need to add ??
i need the Flow that how would i do this ??
```

Comment: I would always start in the manual at the section of the component: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.html

Comment: @hakre the above link is implementing it in ZF.i want to use zf translation classes in core PHP

Comment: Include them by name and just use them? They might work out of the box but I am not Zend Professional that knows that from top of her head, so just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy these files from Zend Library

Zend_Translate.php and Zend_Translate (directory) everything else is in documentation.
You are wrong in thinking that docs says about implementation in ZF. 
Here is example page:

First code snippet from above page:

```
try {
    $translate = new Zend_Translate(
        array(
            'adapter' => 'Company_Translate_Adapter_MyFormat',
            'content' => '/path/to/translate.xx',
            'locale'  => 'en',
            'myoption' => 'myvalue'
        )
    );
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // File not found, no adapter class...
    // General failure
}
```

As you see, there is only Zend_Translate class used. 
All zend library is developed to be quite standalone, which means that you can separate classes by theirs functionalities (you can do it by copy files using class names). More informations you can find in documentation (as always ;))